# Which extra Library or plugin need to install for XPages app using OPENNTF in IBM Notes 9.0.1?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am pretty new to Notes Xpages application. I watched some tutorials from youtube last week, and had some questions here. 
I am using Notes 9.0.1. Is  there any OpenNTF libraries from OpenNTF built-in this release? Do I need install OpenNTF Essentials, OpenNTF Domino API or XPages Extension Library separately? I would like to use bootstrap, ODA and might be some customer control from OpenNTF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extension Lib is part of your Domino 9.0.1 (though it's not the latest as from OpenNTF). If you want to use Bootstrap 4 XPages and ODA you have to install them separately (you can do also for the latest Extlib from OpenNTF).
There are several tutorials you may have found already as you found those Youtube videos.

To use custom controls and other projects from OpenNTF you usually don't have to install anything except that it's stated in the project's release notes.

Comment: If I want to use the latest ExtLib, I have to install by myself. Is that right? Will the IBM version be overridden by the latest version from OpenNTF?

Comment: Yes, if done correctly (I'd recommend via updatesite) it will "override" the built in one. They will be loaded both, but only the latest version will be marked as "active".